# Faker.js v7 clear store

Tags: node.js, faker.js

I use faker.js in gulp to create a lot of unique data

```
faker.helpers.unique
```

Due to debugging, the store is often full and displays the error

`Error: Exceeded maxRetries: 1000 for uniqueness check.`

So I need to clear the store so that faker.js can recreate unique data.

I can't find an instruction to clear the store from the docs, how should I reset/clear the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a builtin method for resetting the store. Right now, your best option is probably to use [your own store implementation](https://github.com/faker-js/faker/discussions/1084#discussioncomment-2990377). You could change maxRetries, override [compare](https://github.com/faker-js/faker/blob/next/src/modules/helpers/unique.ts#L24), use a store that resets on a timer, or have a catch looking for [a FakerError](https://github.com/faker-js/faker/blob/next/src/modules/helpers/unique.ts#L60) with that message, and use that to trigger the reset.

Answer (score 1):

Faker's `unique` is now deprecated. You can use `enforce-unique` to achieve same goal instead of implementing your own store.

```
import { faker } from '@faker-js/faker';
import { UniqueEnforcer } from 'enforce-unique';

const uniqueEnforcer = new UniqueEnforcer();

const uniqueData = uniqueEnforcer.enforce(
  () => {
    // Create your data as you like and return it
    return faker.internet.email();
  },
  {
    // Increase the limits as you need.
    maxTime: 1000 * 60,
    maxRetries: 99999,
  },
);
```

You can create a loop with this to generate thousands of unique data.

Check documentation, https://www.npmjs.com/package/enforce-unique